# How to avoid evaluating the same calculated column in Hive query repetedly

Tags: hive

Lets say I have a calculated column:-

```
select str_to_map("k1:1,k2:2,k3:3")["k1"] as col1,
       str_to_map("k1:1,k2:2,k3:3")["k2"] as col2,
       str_to_map("k1:1,k2:2,k3:3")["k3"] as col3;
```

How do I 'fix' the column calculation only once and access its value multiple times in the query? The map being calculated is the same, only different keys are being accessed for different columns. Performing the same calculation repeatedly is a waste of resources. This example is purposely made too simple, but the point is I want to know how to avoid this kind of redundancy in Hive in general.

Answer (score 0):

In general use subqueries, they are calculated once.

```
select map_col.["k1"] as col1, 
       map_col.["k2"] as col2,
       map_col.["k3"] as col3
from 
(
 select str_to_map("k1:1,k2:2,k3:3") as map_col from table... 
)s;
```

Also you can materialize some query into table to reuse the dataset across different queries or workflows.

Comment: That would be trivial scenario. The real challenge for me is that there is a bigger query that this has to fit in. If I create subquery, there will be join coming into picture. My simple question is -- I want to calculate certain result at row level and use it in calculating multiple columns

Comment: It should behave like how json_tuple behaves when used with lateral views in Hive. It keeps a single row frozen and we can use members inside that row multiple times in the main query without any sort of join. But instead of json_tuple I have other function that returns a Map now the members of that map I want to access for calculating N different columns.

Comment: Subquery is not necessarily JOIN, in my answer this is not a join. You can also use WITH c (sbquery here...) as subq1 and then use in more complex query referencing it as subq1, subquery will be calculated once even for joins. And LATERAL VIEW you have mentioned is basically a join.

Comment: Subquery is exactly matching your question. Join or not join it depends on your decision (your bigger query).

Comment: I purposely created simple query so it is easier for people to answer. Specifically I want to know how to retain a calculated value for the same row so I can use it for multiple columns for that row. This is exactly my question. I don't want to know workaround. I want to know if such a thing is possible in Hive.

Comment: Such thing in Hive is possible and answer is SUBQUERY in general. Also you can use UDFs, also you can use intermediate  tables (cached). All depends on the real use case. You provided simplified question, I provided general solution.